# TupleConstructor with named parameters

Tags: groovy

I have this Script:

```
def person = new Person(lastName: "foo", firstName: "bar")

println person

@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor  
@groovy.transform.ToString(includeNames = true, includeFields=true)  
class Person
{  
   def lastName  
   def firstName  
}
```

why it gives me:

```
Person(lastName:[lastName:foo, firstName:bar], firstName:null)
```

Why firstName remains null and lastName has the map of the parameters?

I am using groovy 1.8.6

Comment: I assume it works if you declare your properties as `String` rather than with `def`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have your fields declared as `def`, the `TupleConstructor` is effectively adding 2 constructors:

```
Person( Object first name )
```

And

```
Person( Object firstName, Object secondName )
```

Then, when you call the map style constructor, it is calling the one arg tuple constructor with the map as the parameter.

Adding types to your fields should remove this issue

As it says in the [docs for TupleConstructor](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html):

> Limitations:
>   - Groovy's normal map-style naming conventions will not be available if the first property (or field) has type LinkedHashMap or if there is a single Map, AbsotractMap or HashMap property (or field)

Comment: The docs(https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) say this: "If there is more than one included property (and/or field) and the first property (or field) has type Object, AbstractMap, Map or HashMap, then a special LinkedHashMap constructor will be created in addition to the tuple constructor to support named parameters in the normal way. This won't be created if the class is already annotated with @MapConstructor or if the defaults annotation attribute is set to false." The 1st prop in your class ends up being type Object after Groovy compiles it.